# Django REST: How to filter related set?

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create a Serializer which contains cities and for every city list of trips which belongs to the current user. The problem is that I'm getting all trips, not just users ones.

My expectation for example if user was two times in London and once in Prague:

```
[{<serialized London>,'trips':[<serialized the two London trips>]},
{<serialized Prague>, 'trips':[<serialized one trip to Prague]}]
```

Now I'm getting all trips connected with the city.

Models:

```
class City(models.Model):
    place_id = models.CharField(max_length=1000, unique=True, null=True, blank=True)
    lat = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=3, db_index=True, null=True, blank=True)
    lng = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=3, db_index=True, null=True, blank=True)

class Trip(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='trips')
    city = models.ForeignKey('locations.City', related_name='trips')
    date_from = models.DateField(default=now)
    date_to = models.DateField(default=now)
    detail = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

View:

```
def ajax_get_my_trips(request):
    trips = Trip.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    cities = City.objects.filter(trips__in=trips)
    response = MyCityTripsSerializer(cities,many=True).data
    return JsonResponse(response, safe=False)
```

Serializers:

```
class MyTripsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Trip
        fields = ('date_from', 'date_to', 'detail')

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return Trip.objects.filter(user=user)


class MyCityTripsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    trips = MyTripsSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = City
        fields = ('place_id', 'lat', 'lng', 'number_of_users_here_now', 'formatted_address', 'trips')
```

Do you know how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyTripsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=UserModel.objects.all())
    city = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=City.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model = Trip
        fields = ('date_from', 'date_to', 'detail')

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return Trip.objects.filter(user=user)


class MyCityTripsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    trips = MyTripsSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = City
        fields = ('place_id', 'lat', 'lng', 'number_of_users_here_now', 'formatted_address', 'trips')


class Trip(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='user_trips')
    city = models.ForeignKey('locations.City', related_name='trips')
    date_from = models.DateField(default=now)
    date_to = models.DateField(default=now)
    detail = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Related name must be unique for every ForeignKey.